# Pay or not to pay last home loan bill before sale?

Tags: home-loan

We are in the process of selling an old house in a few weeks. I am anticipating receiving one last home loan bill before closing that has a due date after closing.

Is it better to ignore this bill and let the closing take care of it?

Or is it better to pay this bill, perhaps even before getting it, to stave off any accruing interest?

My guess is it is not worth paying and let the closing take care of the loan.

Comment: I think you're right that it makes no significant difference, but I Am Not A Lawyer.

Comment: Are you talking about a regular monthly payment or the last and final loan payment?

Comment: Regular monthly payment. If the house sale fell through then it would not be the last monthly payment.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the attorneys handling the closing.

They  may want you to do it early enough so that they can get the accurate payoff amount from the lender. They don't want to hear at closing that you sent in a payment the day before closing.

If there isn't enough time it may be less confusing to wait. But be prepared to make the payment at the last minute if the closing slips.

Comment: **They don't want to hear at closing that you sent in a payment right before closing** (that hasn't had time to post and is not part of their balance inquries)   Yes, I'd wait until after the official closing date before sending it.  And obviously, don't send it if you close.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the risk of a hit to your credit for having a late payment, then not paying the payment is always an option -- just not a wise one.

You didn't state the reason for why you might not want to pay this payment, but if it's due then pay it.  Whether you pay it yourself directly or the closing of the sale settles it and those funds are deducted from the proceeds you receive from the sale, either way you're not going to have that money.

Why would you jeopardize your credit rating over something like this?  Late is late, and that is ***never*** a good thing to have on your credit if it is at all avoidable.  In this instance, you haven't given any reason why you can't pay it.  You are just debating whether or not you *want* to.

If it were me, I'd pay the bill and be done with it.  You avoid serious potential consequences to your credit, and you aren't any better off financially for having not paid it.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: The due date is sufficiently late enough that there is little risk of a late payment, even if the sale fell through. The difference I see is perhaps a difference in the amount of interest that accrues day to day.

Comment: That sheds a bit more light on the subject, but it still begs the question as to why you'd run any risk at all when it financially makes no difference if you pay it up front out of your pocket or it is deducted from the proceeds of the sale.  Unless the amounts involved are large, I doubt the interest differential would be all that significant in and of itself to matter.